# Unable to parse JSON with list

Tags: apex, json, list, jsongenerator

Currently, I'm trying to access JSON with the list included, but when I tried to access the organization from the matches list it's saying variable doesn't exist. Please let me know how to fetch the organization details.

My Sample HTTP Request

```java
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        
request.setEndpoint(baseUrl+method);
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setBody(body);
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
String jsonResponse = response.getBody();
        
System.debug('DEBUG:: API response' + jsonResponse);
        
jsonResponse = jsonResponse.replaceAll('\n','').replaceAll('\r','');
BulkEnrichResponse resp = new BulkEnrichResponse();     
//fromJSON resp = new fromJSON();
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {    
    //resp = (fromJSON)System.JSON.deserialize(jsonResponse, fromJSON.class);
    resp = (BulkEnrichResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(jsonResponse, BulkEnrichResponse.class);
}
```

My JSONResponse parser class:

```java
public class BulkEnrichResponse {
    public List<Matches> matches {get;set;}
    public BulkEnrichResponse()
    {
        
    }

    public class matches
    {
        public Boolean revealed_for_current_team {get;set;} 
        public String email {get;set;} 
        public String email_status {get;set;} 
        public String id {get;set;} 
        public Organization organization {get;set;} 
        public Matches(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'revealed_for_current_team') {
                            revealed_for_current_team = parser.getBooleanValue();
                        } else if (text == 'email') {
                            email = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'email_status') {
                            email_status = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'id') {
                            id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'organization') {
                            organization = new Organization(parser);
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Matches consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    public class Organization 
    {
        public Primary_phone primary_phone {get;set;} 
        public String country {get;set;} 

        public Organization(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'primary_phone') {
                            primary_phone = new Primary_phone(parser);
                        } else if (text == 'country') {
                            country = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Organization consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Primary_phone {
        public String number_Z {get;set;} // in json: number
        public String source {get;set;} 

        public Primary_phone(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'number') {
                            number_Z = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'source') {
                            source = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Primary_phone consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }
}
```

Sample API Response:

```
    {
   "matches":
   [
    {
         "email":"email_not_unlocked@domain.com",
         "email_status":"verified",
         "id":"61c2e2d4bbb92a0001509cce",
         "organization":
         {
            "primary_phone":
            {
               "number":"+1 415-763-6055",
               "source":"Owler"
            },
            "country":"United States"
         },
    },
   ],
}
```

Comment: Sorry @DerekF actually while i'm formatting you made the changes

Comment: Also, why does your deserialization class have constructors that take a JSONParser? Thankfully, you're not using that over `JSON.deserialize()`, but it's adding noise to your code that may make spotting the issue harder.

Comment: Because my API contains multiple matches. So, I'm passing it to the constructor to handle the response

Comment: The only idea that I have at the moment is that maybe `List<Matches> matches` and `Organization organization` might be shadowing. Do you get the same error if you change those class names to `MatchesDeserialized` and `OrganizationDeserialized` (and obviously also changing the name of the class wherever else it gets used)?

Comment: Your idea works like a charm